# &nlsp; HTML space. What was it?

Tags: html

I can not remember what it was that was basically blank, but also worked as a space. It's something like &nlsp; or something like that.

I was using  but I really wanna remember this one. I wish I could word the post better to explain what I'm talking about, but I'm sure someone here understands just by the confusion of &nlsp;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `&nbsp;`. You can find out more about it in several online references, such as [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). It stands for **non-breaking space**.

Answer (score 7):

```
&nbsp;
```

It is used for non-line breaking space in html.

**and**

having too many consecutive &nbsp; is eye itching and bad. If you want bigger space to be generated then use a <span class="spaceOf5px"> <span>. This is useful only as inline space. For block level, use DIV tag.

```
/*CSS for Wide Space Class*/

.spaceOf5px{
    width: 5px;
}

.spaceOf10px{
    width: 10px;
}
```

Remember - there is a space between the span tags.

Answer (score 5):

`&nbsp;` is the HTML entity for non-breaking space. No line break will occur between words separated by a non-breaking space even in the cases where a browser would normally perform text wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp;` is a Non-Breaking SPace in HTML. Normally in HTML, when multiple spaces separate text, as seen here,

```
<h3>Before spaces         After spaces</h3>
```

the browser renders them as only one space:

[image]

However, if you use `&nbsp;`, the browser renders each space as non-breaking:

```
<h3>Before spaces&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;After spaces</h3>
```

The spaces do not collapse to one (hence 'non-breaking'). Each space is rendered:

[image]